# how to secure / disable the spark web ui

Tags: .htaccess, nginx, apache-spark

I'm trying to password protect the spark web ui of my spark cluster. I've looked at the [security doc](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/security.html). Usually the spark doc has many examples on how to do things, but for some reason, none is provided in this case. I don't feel comfortable enough for creating my own javax servlet filter, nor properly connecting it to whatever it is supposed to be connected to.

So I've tried protecting it with an nginx htaccess setup - this would be way enough for my purpose. unfortunately, when I run the cluster it avoids the 8080 port and switches to 8081 - saying that 8080 is not accessible.

Has anyone tried to password protect a spark web ui?

Comment: Are you trying to protect only from a remote access or a local as well? If it is the first case you can set ports using `SPARK_[MASTER|WORKER]_WEBUI_PORT`, block remote access using system level solutions (`iptables`, `ufw`) and then configure Nginx to secure remote connections. It won't solve the problem of the local access though.

Comment: So basically, I'd like to protect the access to http://my_server:8080 from anyone on the internet. As long as someone as the url, he can currently access the page and kill any of my tasks.I'd like to require the user to provide a password before being able to see and interact with the page. So I'm not sure if I mean remote or local. Sorry for not being more specific...

Answer (score 1):

**Disclaimer**: It is an extremely naive approach and you shouldn't depend on it in a production environment. Moreover I assume you don't use this instance of Nginx and you have access to standard ports (80|443).

1. Configure Spark to use a port of your choice. You can use `SPARK_MASTER_WEBUI_PORT` variable. Below I assume it is 8080.
2. Generate self-signed certificates for your server. You can find multiple good resources how to do it so just to make this answer complete lets use example from [Linode guide](https://www.linode.com/docs/security/ssl/how-to-provide-encrypted-access-to-resources-using-ssl-certificated-on-nginx):

   ```
   openssl req -new -x509 -sha256 -days 365 -nodes -out /path/to/nginx.pem -keyout /path/to/nginx.key
   ```
3. Make sure that key has limited access rights

   ```
   chmod 400 /path/to/nginx.key
   ```
4. Generate htpasswd file

   ```
   htpasswd -b -c /path/to/passwdfile username password
   ```
5. Remove default configuration from `nginx/sites-enabled`
6. Create a simple reverse proxy configuration and add it to ``nginx/sites-enabled`

   ```
   server {
       # Adjust port number if cannot use ports below 1024
       listen 443 ssl;

       ssl_certificate      /path/to/nginx.pem;
       ssl_certificate_key  /path/to/nginx.key;  

       location / {
           proxy_set_header Host $host;
           proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
           proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
           auth_basic           "closed site";
           auth_basic_user_file /path/to/passwdfile;
       }   
   }
   ```
7. Configure your system to reject remote connections to web UI port.

To make it work web UI has to be accessible from localhost so everyone who has access to your master can reach web UI directly.

Comment: makes sense... However, you're kind of scaring me with that disclaimer ! I intend to use it in prod. But I guess it's better than nothing anyway. I'm going to try that, and see if someone comes up with a more 'official' approach. Thanks !

Comment: Because the executor web UI runs on every slave at :4040 you'll either need to block 4040 at the firewall for all of those machines (and just live without convenient access to logs) or perform the same configuration nginx configuration on each slave.

Comment: @cfeduke Feel free to edit the answer :) If you prefer I can turn it into community wiki.